# Search with SELF JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, self-join

Please help to figure it out the right SQL statement for the search. I use SELF JOIN and I get the right results, but I can't get `CONCAT_WS` to work the right way.

DATA:

```
id  base_id name                                type
2   0       Alien Isolation                     Base
5   0       Aliens vs. Predator                 Base
4   0       Aliens versus Predator Classic 2000 Base
6   0       Assassin's Creed                    Base
8   2       Corporate Lockdown                  DLC
9   2       Crew Expendable                     DLC
10  2       Trauma                              DLC
11  2       Last Survivor                       DLC
12  2       Safe Haven                          DLC
13  2       Lost Contact                        DLC
14  1       The Trigger                         DLC
22  0       Age of Wonders III                  Base
23  2       Alien Batman                        DLC
```

SELECT all base games:

```
    SELECT games.id, games.name, games.type, COUNT(dlc.base_id) AS dlc_count
    FROM games
    LEFT JOIN games dlc
    ON games.id = dlc.base_id
    WHERE games.base_id = 0
    GROUP BY games.id
    ORDER BY games.name ASC
    LIMIT 0, 10
```

RESULTS:

```
id  name                                type    dlc_count
22  Age of Wonders III                  Base    0
2   Alien Isolation                     Base    7
4   Aliens versus Predator Classic 2000 Base    0
5   Aliens vs. Predator                 Base    0
6   Assassin's Creed                    Base    0
```

SEARCH for word "alien" showing base name for the dlc

```
    SELECT games.id, CONCAT_WS(' -> ', games.name, dlc.name) AS name, games.type, COUNT(dlc.base_id) AS dlc_count
    FROM games
    LEFT JOIN games dlc
    ON games.id = dlc.base_id
    WHERE MATCH(games.name) AGAINST('alien*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    GROUP BY games.id
    ORDER BY games.name ASC
    LIMIT 0, 10
```

I GET THESE RESULTS:

```
id  name                                    type    dlc_count   
23  Alien Batman                            DLC     0
2   Alien Isolation -> Corporate Lockdown   Base    7
4   Aliens versus Predator Classic 2000     Base    0
5   Aliens vs. Predator                     Base    0
```

AND THEY SHOULD BE:

```
id  name                                    type    dlc_count   
23  Alien Isolation  -> Alien Batman        DLC     0
2   Alien Isolation                         Base    7
4   Aliens versus Predator Classic 2000     Base    0
5   Aliens vs. Predator                     Base    0
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN games dlc
    ON games.id = dlc.base_id` This is the reason you get the row with name 'Alien Isolation -> Corporate Lockdown'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this SQL

```
select 
    id, 
    concat_ws(
        ' -> ',
        ( select base.name from games as base where base.id = games.base_id ),
        name
    ) as concat_name, 
    games.type, 
    ( select count(dlc.base_id) from games as dlc where dlc.base_id = games.id )  as dlc_count

from games where 
    match(name) against('alien*' in boolean mode)

order by name asc

limit 0, 10
```

Comment: Yes, this solution works and thank you for the solution. But I was wondering if is it possible to do that without sub-queries. I mean if is it possible to do only joins...

Comment: Not sure if it's possible with sub selects the way you want your results. You don't need just a single join, you need 2 joins... one join that joins the base_id with the id to get the base name and one that goes the other way matching the id with the base_id to get the dlc count

Comment: Yep, I was afraid of that :) I have to use 2 joins. Just wanted to be sure. So can I ask what is better - to use sub-queries or 2 joins? Generally sub-queries should be slower.

Comment: Well... I started using sub queries many years ago, and haven't looked back since. It's just easier for me to understand. So, if there is a way to write it using joins, I'm not sure how. I'd have to look up the docs on joins again... lol. As far as speed. MySQL is pretty smart now and I haven't had any issues with sub queries being slow if you have the right indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a bit hard to follow.  You seem to want the count of all "dlc"s in the last column.  However, you only want the dlc name that contains "Alien".  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT g.id,
       CONCAT_WS(' -> ',
                 MAX(CASE WHEN lower(dlc.name) LIKE '%alien%' THEN dlc.name END), g.name) AS name, g.type,    
       COUNT(dlc.base_id) AS dlc_count
FROM games g LEFT JOIN
     games dlc
     ON g.id = dlc.base_id
WHERE MATCH(g.name) AGAINST('alien*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
GROUP BY g.id, g.name
ORDER BY g.name ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Well, I'll try to explain.

Comment: Well, I'll try to explain. I search for the word "alien" in base games. So all alien should apear in the results, but I also search for the word in dlc's and if the is a word it should display the base name and also the dlc name. And right now your solution does not show "alien isolation" as separate hit. So it should show "alien isolation" and "alien isolation -> alien batman". And the count is to show how many dlc's the base game has.